# What does new (int) (constructor) syntax mean in C++?

Tags: c++

So I was looking at LLVM's `Call` instruction code, and it has a public constructor like so:

```
  static CallInst *Create(FunctionType *Ty, Value *Func, ArrayRef<Value *> Args,
                          const Twine &NameStr,
                          Instruction *InsertBefore = nullptr) {
    return new (ComputeNumOperands(Args.size()))
        CallInst(Ty, Func, Args, None, NameStr, InsertBefore);
  }
```

`Create` calls the appropriate private consstructor `CallInst`, but with an integer which I don't understand.

This is the code for `ComputeNumOperands`, and you can see that it returns `int`.

```
  /// Compute the number of operands to allocate.
  static int ComputeNumOperands(int NumArgs, int NumBundleInputs = 0) {
    // We need one operand for the called function, plus the input operand
    // counts provided.
    return 1 + NumArgs + NumBundleInputs;
  }
```

Hence my question: what does `new int Constructor()` mean?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it allocates the object in the space pointed to by the `int`. However, I cannot reconcile that knowledge with this use case. In this case, the `int` is `Number of arguments + 1`, which could point to anything!

Comment: @Advait — something’s wrong here. That argument should be a pointer, not an `int`. The pointer points at the location where the object should be constructed.

Comment: Beware the C++17 shenanigans, it made placement new a lot more versatile.  Mostly to pass alignment requirements to the allocator, solving a long-standing fugly problem, but anything goes.  You probably have to find that allocator to get ahead.

Comment: Not a great duplicate, is it?  08 < 17.